# Android Eddystone broadcast data too large

Tags: java, android, maxlength, bluetooth-lowenergy, eddystone

I am trying to develop a Eddystone based app. 
I took the google sample code and tried modifying it.
The android specs says maximum length of service data is 31 bytes

I tried changing the service data length in the following code
buildServiceData()

Here maximum it accepts 20 bytes only.
more than that (ex 21 bytes) I get the
ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE error

> //error
>   Class: AdvertiseCallback
>   Error : ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE
>   Failed to start advertising as the advertise data to be broadcasted is larger than 31 bytes.

I am using the UID frame and testing on a lollipop device.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
byte[] serviceData = null;        

    //  1+1+10+6+1+1+1   = 21 bytes
     private byte[] buildServiceData() throws IOException {           
     byte txPower = txPowerLevelToByteValue();          
     byte[] namespaceBytes = toByteArray(namespace.getText().toString());              
     byte[] instanceBytes = toByteArray(instance.getText().toString());             
     ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();      
     os.write(new byte[]{FRAME_TYPE_UID, txPower});       

     os.write(namespaceBytes);             
     os.write(instanceBytes);                      

//for testing only          
 //  os.write(new byte[]{txPower});          
  // os.write(new byte[]{txPower});       
  //    os.write(new byte[]{txPower});               
       return os.toByteArray();       

 }

 //advertise the data
 AdvertiseData advertiseData = new AdvertiseData.Builder()             .addServiceData(SERVICE_UUID, serviceData)             .addServiceUuid(SERVICE_UUID)             
.setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)            
 .setIncludeDeviceName(false)             
.build();                  

namespace.setError(null);         
instance.setError(null);         

setEnabledViews(false, namespace, instance, rndNamespace, rndInstance, txPower, txMode);         
adv.startAdvertising(advertiseSettings, advertiseData, advertiseCallback);
```

Comment: In one mobile with minimum spec and Android 8.1.0 (Oreo Go) I can attach only one out of .addServiceData(SERVICE_UUID, serviceData)  and addServiceUuid(SERVICE_UUID)  (no question of adding .setIncludeDeviceName(true) ). With only .addServiceData(SERVICE_UUID, serviceData) I can send the serviceData upto 10 bytes without fail. I have another mobile with moderate spec and Android 7.1.2 (Nougat), where I can receive the signal but serviceRecord.getServiceData() returns a blank Map. But from Nougat, I can send the data up to 24 bytes. And in Oreo Go I can retrieve the data, the Map is not empty

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `serviceData` is not being formatted correctly, such that its length is becoming too large. It's hard to say exactly why, because not all of the code is shown.

I'd suggest you check the length of the serviceData to see if mis-formatting is making it too long.  It might also be helpful to print out the byte array as a hex string and paste it in your question if it isn't obvious what is causing it to be malformed.

You can print out your serviceData with code like this:

```
// Put this line near the "advertise the data" comment
Log.d(TAG, "Service data bytes: "+byteArayToHexString(serviceData));


public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", bytes[i]));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Service data bytes: 00f040e6b49dc957ce78f5f972734c56f0ab - no error
Service data bytes: 00f040e6b49dc957ce78f5f972734c56f0abf0f0f0 - error

Comment: as i mentioned it works upto 20 bytes and gives error when it exceeds 20 bytes

Comment: Well, for a standard Eddystone-UID frame, you only need 18 bytes of data, yes?  So you can transmit one successfully.   What you are trying to do is send a bigger non-standard Eddystone-UID frame.   Nothing wrong with that -- I just want to clarify what you are trying to do.  And I do not believe it is true that you can send 31 bytes of service data.   Where did you find that documented?

Comment: the android developer doc   Class: AdvertiseCallback
ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE
Failed to start advertising as the advertise data to be broadcasted is larger than 31 bytes. I mentioned it in my description. The doc clearly mentions 31 bytes. I want to send some additional  data in the UID frame itself without using other frames (TLM and URL).